# How can I add to a RichTextbox also the colored string and the rest of the string?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

```
foreach(string line in lines)
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText(line);
    RichTextBoxExtensions.AppendText(richTextBox1, "Ready: ", Color.Red);
}
```

If line is

> "Hello world"

so what I want to have is in the first line in the `RichTextBox1`:

> Ready Hello world

where Ready is in Red color only Ready.

In the next line again

> Ready hi hello

Again Ready is in red but hi hello in it's original color not changed.

But what I'm getting is mess the world Ready is added in the end after line and it's not in Red color only in the first line.

Also in the `RichTextBox` all the lines and Ready added as text block not as lines.

What I want to see in the `RichTextBox` when running the program is lines:

> Ready: Hello world
>   Ready: Hi hello
>   Ready: This is a line
>   Ready: Hi everyone

And only

> Ready:

is in Red

```
public class RichTextBoxExtensions
{
    public static void AppendText(RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
    {
        box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
        box.SelectionLength = 0;

        box.SelectionColor = color;
        box.AppendText(text);
        box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
    }
    public static void UpdateText(RichTextBox box, string find, string replace, Color? color)
    {
        box.SelectionStart = box.Find(find, RichTextBoxFinds.Reverse);
        box.SelectionLength = find.Length;
        box.SelectionColor = color ?? box.SelectionColor;
        box.SelectedText = replace;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse the 2 lines of code in your for-loop, and add `Environment.NewLine`.
This minor correction :

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    RichTextBoxExtensions.AppendText(richTextBox1, "Ready: ", Color.Red);
    richTextBox1.AppendText(line + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Testing it with this list:

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>() { "Hello world", "hi hello", "this is a line"};
```

brings about this Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do it like this

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Font = new Font("Consolas", 18f, FontStyle.Bold);
        richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
        string[] words =
        {
            "a",
            "b",
            "c",
            "d",
            "e",
            "f",
            "g."
        };
        Color[] colors =
        {
            Color.Aqua,
            Color.CadetBlue,
            Color.Cornsilk,
            Color.Gold,
            Color.HotPink,
            Color.Lavender,
            Color.Moccasin
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            string word = words[i];
            Color color = colors[i];
            {
                richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = color;
                richTextBox1.AppendText(word);
                richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
                richTextBox1.AppendText(" ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}